# Mapping nested CoreData Objects with RestKit results in validation error

Tags: ios, json, core-data, mapping, restkit

I have used RestKit for object mapping some times, but this is the first time with core data objects.

I will map the nested json content into two core data entities. This results in a validation error - failing the mapping.

Any suggestions why the relationship is failing?

```
 E restkit.object_mapping:RKMappingOperation.m:335 Validation failed while mapping attribute at key path 'workflowSteps' to value {(
<NUWorkflowStepMO: 0xe717a00> (entity: WorkflowSteps; id: 0xe717a40 <x-coredata:///WorkflowSteps/t150ED0DB-CADD-46FD-804F-1F2094B7C7DF194> ; data: {
operatingCompany = nil;
"operatingCompany_id" = 475;
position = 2;
step = SecurityCheck;
uid = 222;
}),
<NUWorkflowStepMO: 0xe88c1a0> (entity: WorkflowSteps; id: 0xe8e5a50 <x-coredata:///WorkflowSteps/t150ED0DB-CADD-46FD-804F-1F2094B7C7DF195> ; data: {
operatingCompany = nil;
"operatingCompany_id" = 475;
position = 3;
step = "Mission Complete";
uid = 333;
}),
<NUWorkflowStepMO: 0xe7194b0> (entity: WorkflowSteps; id: 0xe7194a0 <x-coredata:///WorkflowSteps/t150ED0DB-CADD-46FD-804F-1F2094B7C7DF193> ; data: {
operatingCompany = nil;
"operatingCompany_id" = 475;
position = 1;
step = Welcome;
uid = 111;
})
)}. Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)
2014-07-24 14:39:23.868 NuBON-Dev[43457:60b] E restkit:RKLog.m:151 Validation Error
                    NSLocalizedDescriptionKey:      The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 1550.)
                    NSValidationKeyErrorKey:            workflowSteps
                    NSValidationPredicateErrorKey:  (null)
                    NSValidationObjectErrorKey:
<NUOperatingCompanyMO: 0xe9c3be0> (entity: OperatingCompany; id: 0xe9c3c20 <x- coredata:///OperatingCompany/t150ED0DB-CADD-46FD-804F-1F2094B7C7DF192> ; data: {
categoryId = 0;
workflowSteps =     (
);
uid = 475;
})
```

This ist the json:

```
{
"operatingCompanyIds":[
                       475
                       ],
"itemCount":1,
"items":[
         {
         "id":475,
         "workflowStep":[
                                 {
                                 "id":111,
                                 "operatingCompany_id":475,
                                 "step":"Welcome",
                                 "position":1
                                 },
                                 {
                                 "id":222,
                                 "operatingCompany_id":475,
                                 "step":"SecurityCheck",
                                 "position":2
                                 },
                                 {
                                 "id":333,
                                 "operatingCompany_id":475,
                                 "step":"Mission Complete",
                                 "position":3
                                 }
                                 ],
         "categoryId":3,
         }
         ]
}
```

I have a core data model with the two entities "item" and "workflowStep", item has a to-many relationship with workflowSteps.

Here is my mapping:

OperatingCompany:

```
+ (NSDictionary*) mappingDictionary {
return @{
         @"id": @"uid",
         @"name": @"name",
         @"category_id": @"category_id",
         };
}

 + (RKEntityMapping*) entityMappingForManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore {
RKEntityMapping* mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[NUOperatingCompanyMO entityName] inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"uid"]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[NUOperatingCompanyMO mappingDictionary]];

RKRelationshipMapping* relationshipMapping = [RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"workflowStep" toKeyPath:@"workflowSteps" withMapping:[NUCheckoutWorkStepMO entityMappingForManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore]];
[mapping addPropertyMapping:relationshipMapping];
}
```

WorkflowStep

```
+ (NSDictionary*) mappingDictionary {
return @{
         @"id": @"uid",
         @"operatingCompany_id": @"operatingCompany_id",
         @"step": @"step",
         @"position": @"position"
         };
}

+ (RKEntityMapping*) entityMappingForManagedObjectStore:(RKManagedObjectStore *)managedObjectStore {
RKEntityMapping* mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:[NUCheckoutWorkStepMO entityName] inManagedObjectStore:managedObjectStore];
[mapping setIdentificationAttributes:@[@"uid"]];
[mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[NUCheckoutWorkStepMO mappingDictionary]];

[mapping addConnectionForRelationship:@"operatingCompany" connectedBy:@"uid"];

return mapping;
}
```

Comment: Is anything in your model non-optional? Like `operatingCompany`? Your `addConnectionForRelationship:` looks to use the wrong source key name (`uid` instead of `operatingCompany_id`).

Comment: @Wain All entity attributes and relations (especially the relation from the validation error: NSValidationKeyErrorKey: workflowSteps) are optional. I debugged even the RestKit validation as far as i could. Restkit maps correctly all nested objects, results in a set with 3 objects and calls '[self.destinationObject validateValue:value forKeyPath:keyPath error:&validationError];' destination object is the item (attributes mapped correctly) and value is the set with the workflowSteps. Keypath is "workflowSteps". This is all correct. I can not debug inside the apple code an see validation problem.